# Auto highlighting text when paste a new content

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlighting

This is my first post here.

I have Emacs installed at work and at home. The functionality is slightly different when I use highlighting and I cannot figure out which options to change.

At work, I applied a couple of `highlight-regexp` for a number of patterns on temporary buffer (`C-x b`). I am pretty sure that when I posted a new content of another text, Emacs highlighted a new content. Also, when I typed a new word and that word matched one of the regexps, Emacs automatically highlighted the word.

At home, this functionality is missing and I don't know how to turn it on. It's really useful!

---

Edit.

I have only added a few functions in `.emacs` to have: a larger window, no welcome screen, and access to MELPA. Apart from that, I installed a custom color theme (the link [here](https://github.com/pomeo/oblivion-emacs)). But this extra package is installed in both versions of Emacs i have at home and at work.

The content of `.emacs`:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-names-vector ["#242424" "#e5786d" "#95e454" "#cae682" "#8ac6f2" "#333366" "#ccaa8f" "#f6f3e8"])
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (atom-dark)))
 '(custom-safe-themes (quote ("ed066c6e5b9d72b2b2acce51bc944b396b82e5338c79135888c584d6979f5cd2" "c64bcaa2a93cf797e7a2f860d0545f8de1833feda24c680bd56ee76d88c06948" default))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

 ;; Custom wind size
 (if (display-graphic-p)
   (progn
     (setq initial-frame-alist
       '(
         (tool-bar-lines . 0)
         (width . 136) ; chars
         (height . 46) ; lines
         ;;
         ))

   (setq default-frame-alist
     '(
       (tool-bar-lines . 0)
       (width . 136)
       (height . 46)
       ;;
       )))
   (progn
     (setq initial-frame-alist
       '(
         (tool-bar-lines . 0)))
     (setq default-frame-alist
       '(
         (tool-bar-lines . 0)))))

 ;; No welcome text
 (setq inhibit-startup-screen t)

 ;; load emacs 24's package system. Add MELPA repository.
 (when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
   (require 'package)
   (add-to-list
     'package-archives
     ;; '("melpa" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") ; many packages won't show if using stable
     '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
     t))
```

---

Edit 2.

Possible variables related to `hi-lock-*`:

```
hi-lock-archaic-interface-deduce    hi-lock-archaic-interface-message-used
hi-lock-exclude-modes               hi-lock-face-defaults
hi-lock-face-history                hi-lock-file-patterns
hi-lock-file-patterns-policy        hi-lock-file-patterns-prefix
hi-lock-file-patterns-range         hi-lock-highlight-range
hi-lock-interactive-patterns        hi-lock-map
hi-lock-menu                        hi-lock-mode
hi-lock-mode-major-mode             hi-lock-regexp-history
hi-lock-string-serialize-hash       hi-lock-string-serialize-serial
```

Possible variables related to `global-hi-lock-*`

```
global-hi-lock-mode
global-hi-lock-mode-buffers
```

Comment: seem to work perfectly here, when you type `M-x highlight-regexp` does the interactive prompt ask you for the regexp and then for the highlight face? also is Hi-lock mode enabled in the buffer you are trying?

Comment: Are versions of Emacs identical? Are you using the same init file on both installations?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I use CentOS 7 at both work and home and Emacs is installed from a package (via `yum`). The version at home is __GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)__. I am sure the same version is at work.

Comment: @manandearth It does ask for both regexp and highlight colour. I tried both  modes of Hi-lock: on and off. If I turn off hi-lock, highlighting disappears.

Comment: I removed `.emacs` and `.emacs.d/`, uninstalled and installed Emacs again. I run its fresh version without any packages and the behaviour is the same. It does not highlight new content. Surprisingly, `unhighlight-regexp` ask for regexp to unhighlight, e.g. if I type `highlight-regexp` and provide, e.g. "one" for regexp, `unhighlight-regexp` will ask to remove highlighting this pattern, e.g. "one".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this: "a fae that will be obviously visible". The text is visible; I can either work on an existing file or just a temporary buffer (<kbd>C-x b</kbd> and e.g. `temp` to create one). As to `Global-hi-lock` or `Hi-lock`, I don't have them to be honest. I tested `hi-lock-mode` and `global-hi-lock-mode` (<kbd>C-h v</kbd>). The former is true, the latter us nil.

Comment: @manandearth I edited question and added what would be possible completion for `hi-lock` and `global-hi-lock`

Comment: I have started emacs with your setup and the `highlight-regexp` works fine. I am running: GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.26)

Comment: hi-lock is the mode that runs the `highlight-regexp` note that when you run that command it shows as `Hi` in the mode line. I suggested turning it on globally to try and see the effect as I can't manage to replicate the problem that you encounter.

Comment: @manandearth Thanks for doing it. I really appreciate it! I have installed GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.10) of 2018-03-24 from sources and the behaviours is exactly the same! I run Centos 7 with a custom Gnome Shell Theme. It indeed shows "Hi" when highlighting is on and I can see words highlighted but Emacs does not highlight any new word matching the pattern! Just to confirm, when you type "aaa xyz aaa", turn on highlight regexp with "aaa", highlight existing words, then type new words "aaa", you have them all highlighted? I guess you do, just confirming that.Ty

Comment: yes indeed. works perfectly.

Comment: This is crazy :/ It looks like something's wrong outside Emacs. I will have to investigate it. Ty

Comment: I am on fresh system with nothing else but emacs. I tried to install Emacs from both repositories and compile from sources. The behaviour is the same. New words don't get highlighted even though I am in "Hi" mode... Which makes me consider it must be something inside Emacs!!!

Comment: Apparently, there is another variable which control auto update buffer while highlighting is on, that is `font-lock-mode`. If that variable is on, new content is highlighted automatically. Thanks to the answer on reddit ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/8701i6/problems_with_hilock_in_current_buffer/))

Comment: @manandearth Hello. I hope you have not abandoned this topic. Please can you give me one more detail (last)? Is buffer in which auto highlighting works (Hi-mode on) a Fundamental (like a new empty one) or a programming mode, e.g. Lisp Interaction; particularly Lisp Interaction is important. On both versions: 24 and 25.3 on PC and Mac, Emacs does not auto highlight a new content if I make a new buffer, that is Fundamental by default. On the other hand, *scratch* buffer, the one created Emacs at start, is the Lisp Interaction and auto highlighting works all right in *scratch*.

Comment: You are right. On fundamental mode highlight-regex doesn't highlight new content. I think you can submit a bug there and try to find an alternative to fundemental, or an alternative to hi-lock mode.